Buildroot SPL file for i.mx53
I'm working with buildroot. I need to SPL file for SD card booting. But when I select the SPL in the menuconfig, make processes failed with ...SPL No such file or directory.
How can I generate the SPL file with Buildroot
enter image description here

I think the SPL file no rule for imx53 target. If I am right, which file require/enough for boot for imx.53. I don't see specific explanation for this
